# Pausing and Resuming audio recording on Win-RT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

**Can anyone help me to code in WinRT for PAUSING and RESUMING recording audio files.**

Classes used are as follows:

**IRamdomAccessStream**   for storing captured voice to random stream.

**Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture**  for capturing audio voice.

**Windows.Storage.StorageFile** for storing file.

Please help me with the code that how to pause the stream and again on resume the captured voice append to the existing stream.

waiting 4 the reply..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this had been down voted.  Have a look at [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622), it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

The sample linked above provides indeed a good start about how to work with audio/video capture within a WinRT app.
However, there's no scenario in the samples replying the original question:
It seems indeed there are no methods that support pausing in MediaCapture.
The only Store App available that supports pausing while recording that I can see it's [Windows Sound Recorder from Microsoft](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/9f03273f-fe0b-4ed8-9bc8-c2f256375490).
I assume that App is written in C++ and uses a custom sink instead to record audio which also supports appending data to an existing stream.